Condition on limit of adapted processes to be adapted
Assume we have a stochastic process $(X^{n}_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}$, which is $\mathcal{F}_{t}$ measurable. $( \mathcal{F}_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}$ is a filtration on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. What type of (stochastic) convergence
$(X^{n}_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}  \to  (X_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}$
ensures us that $(X_{t})_{t \in [0,T]}$ is still a adapted process.
My idea is as follows: Since measurability of functions is transferred to the limit value with point-by-point convergence. So if we have almost sure convergence we can set the process just $0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega_{0}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_{0}) = 0$ (the events where the convergence doesnt take place). So as long as the filtration is completed (all zero sets are in $\mathcal{F}_{t}$) this should be enough? Is this right and are there more possibilities of convergences which preserve adaptability?

You will need one null set outside with $X_t^{n} \to X_t$ for every $t$. The null set cannot depend on $t$.
